# What is the better implementation? MongoDb Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need some help with MongoDb. I need to check if an object exists in the database. If it's true, then I need to check if this object has a specific element into array (Products). If not, I need to create this object(Order) with this element(Cookie) in to array(Products).

Example data:

```
Order { 
   _id: ObjectId("580bc55f54101f1d18152d88"),
   code: "AVG223424",
   products: [
     {
        name: "Cookie"     
     }, 
     {
        name: "Soda"     
     }
   ]
}
```

Finally, what is the better implementation?

Comment: When you say you need to check if an object exists in the database, what is criteria are you checking based on?  Do you have the ObjectId or the 'code'?  If not, what is the criteria?

Comment: The criteria is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a collection with the name 'Orders'

```
    db
    .Orders
    .update({
        code: "12345"
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            products: {
                name: "Cookie"
            }
        },
        $setOnInsert: {
            code: "12345"
        }

    }, {
        upsert: true
    });
```

This query looks for a document with the same 'code,' and if found, will add the object '{name: "Cookie"}' if there is no other Object with the same key/val pairs.  If the document does not exist, the '$setOnInsert' command will set the specified fields *only* if a new document is created.